# Java - Difference between fixed-sized list and list with initial capacity specified

Tags: java, arrays, list, collections

I am having an issue in understanding this.

while we do

```
 List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(array);
```

we can not use methods like add, remove on that list. I know that Arrays.asList() returns a fixed-sized list.

What I don't understand is if we create a list with initial capacity specified like

```
List<Integer> list2 = new ArrayList<Integer>(10);
```

we can perform all the operations on that list. What is the difference between fixed-sized list and list with initial capacity specified?

I have read many answers on this but having such a hard time understanding this. Can anyone explain?

Thanks.

Comment: `Arrays.asList(array)` acts as bridge between array-based and collection-based APIs. Whereas setting an initial size alleviates the need to create another array with twice the size so frequently.

Comment: @JonnyHenly Yes I read that but couldn't understand. At the end, we are getting the list right.

Comment: No, `Arrays.asList(array)` returns an implementation of `List` that can't be resized. While the other creates a `List` with an initial capacity.

Comment: 'implementation of List' - I don't understand. Can you be more specific?

Comment: @HalfBloodPrince The created ArrayList is not java.lang.ArrayList class, it is Arrays.ArrayList which extends AbstractList.  Now the AbstractList methods add/remove/set operations throw UnsupportedOperationException.  Have a look at the comment in the AbstractList class: "This class provides a skeletal implementation of the {@link List} interface to minimize ... ".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Arrays.asList(array)` returns an object of type `java.util.Arrays.ArrayList`, which does not support add and remove operations.

While the code below will return an object of type `java.util.ArrayList`, which supports add and remove operations.

```
List<Integer> list2 = new ArrayList<Integer>(10);`
```

Comment: Arrays.asList(array) is returning java.util.List.

Comment: First increase your capability to understand the question, he thinks that both implementation is same, but its not the case.

Comment: @JonnyHenly I think you are missing the point here. Stifler is correct in saying that both are returning different objects and that is the point here.

Comment: @HalfBloodPrince, Please check the Java source code

Comment: @Siddharth No, what happened is that this answer has bad formatting and I thought the line `java.util.Arrays.ArrayList` was `java.util.ArrayList`. After re-reading that, I changed my downvote to an upvote.

Comment: @HalfBloodPrince java.util.List, but not java.util.ArrayList. Arrays.asList return java.util.Arrays.ArrayList

Comment: @Rustam It is returning java.util.List or java.util.Arrays.ArrayList? I am confused.

Comment: @HalfBloodPrince actually, it returns both. `java.util.List`is an interface, whereas `java.util.Array.ArrayList`is an implementation of this interface.

Answer (score 4):

Very simply, `Arrays.asList` is so you can use `List` methods with an array. `ArrayList(int)` is for when you need to create a really large `ArrayList` and want to help speed things up a bit.

**In more detail:** the `List` returned by `asList` is intended as a wrapper to an array. Since you cannot resize an array, the methods that change the size of a `List` are unimplemented. Most of the time I just use `asList` to add a fixed number of elements to a collection simply. eg.

```
new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("hello", "world"));
```

Confusingly, the implementation of `ArrayList` is very similar -- it's a `List` backed by an array. However, `ArrayList` allows you to change it's size. To do this it keeps a separate fields about the how many objects are in the list and the length of the backing array. Add an element and the `ArrayList` just sets `array[size]` to the element and then increments the `size` field. But what if `array[size]` is out of bounds? At this point the `ArrayList` creates a new, larger array and copies over the elements from the previous backing array. However, if you are creating a large `List` then this constant creation of new backing arrays can start to take up a lot of time. As such, if you know the approximate number of elements that will be in the `List` you can use this to inform the `ArrayList` about the size of the initial backing array it should create. This is what the `ArrayList(int)` constructor is for. Only in exceptional circumstances will you need to worry about giving the `ArrayList` a length hint.

Comment: very well explained. Just tell me that `Arrays.asList(array)` returns   `java.util.List` or `java.util.Arrays.ArrayList`. What I see is the method is returning `java.util.List` but here many are telling that it returns `java.util.Arrays.ArrayList`. Really confusede about it.

Comment: It doesn't really matter. But both are right and wrong in their own way. The return type of the function is `List`, so you know you have an instance of `List`. But `List` is an interface, so you can't create objects whose class is `List`. `Arrays.ArrayList`  *implements* `List` and provides the implementation detail of how to `get` and `set` an item in the `List`. Thus, the actual class of the object is `Arrays.ArrayList`, but that's not important -- so the return type is only listed as `List`. This is called polymorphism.